# Help with a simple SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a fairly large SPROC I'm working on. Well, large as far as I am concerned since I haven't written SQL in quite some time. Anyway, I want to make this Update statement work:

```
update @salesCommission
set LineAmountWithCashDiscount = (LineAmount - ((LineAmount/ (
   select SUM(LineAmount)
   FROM  @salesCommission
   WHERE InvoiceNumber='00072766')) * CashDiscountAmount))
```

My problem is that I need to replace the:

WHERE InvoiceNumber='00072766'

clause so that the invoice number is not hard coded. Instead it should just be the invoice number of the current row being updated.

Can anyone show me how to re-write this update query so that it selects the sum of the LineAmount for the current row being updated?

Comment: Is this SQL Server? I assume @salescommission is a table variable?

Comment: Yes @salescommission is a table variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update S
SET LineAmountWithCashDiscount = S.LineAmount - (S.LineAmount / I.Total) * CashDiscountAmount
FROM @salesCommission S
inner join
(
select InvoiceNumber,
    CASE WHEN SUM(LineAmount) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE SUM(LineAmount) END as Total 
from @salesCommission
group by InvoiceNumber
) I on I.InvoiceNumber = S.InvoiceNumber
```

EDIT: The case to turn "total" into 1 when 0 is to get around #Div/0 errors

Comment: I think this is about it. The SPROC alters ok but I get a divide by zero in this part of it. I think sometimes the total can be zero.

Comment: update S
SET LineAmountWithCashDiscount = S.LineAmount - (S.LineAmount / I.Total) * CashDiscountAmount
FROM @salesCommission S
inner join
(
select InvoiceNumber, CASE WHEN SUM(LineAmount) = 0 THEN 
   1 
    ELSE 
   SUM(LineAmount)
    END as Total
from @salesCommission
group by InvoiceNumber
) I on I.InvoiceNumber = S.InvoiceNumber

Comment: I modded yours cyberkiwi to the above comment and it seems to work.

Comment: @Brent - ah I see. the division by zero problem. answer edited

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in a stored procedure that's being called by a trigger...

`update @salesCommission 
set LineAmountWithCashDiscount = 
(LineAmount - ((LineAmount/ (select SUM(LineAmount) 
FROM  @salesCommission WHERE InvoiceNumber=(Select InvoiceNumber from Inserted)
)) * CashDiscountAmount))`